# let scrollview fill out whole screen except for height of relative layout at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, scrollview, fill

I'm stuck on how to fill the whole screen with a top layout except for the space needed for a bottom layout. I'm using relative layouts to place the layouts as needed, but I want my top view to take up all space except the space needed for my bottom view (the top view height will change depending on user input). See xml below. Right now, my top view will only take up as much space as the linearlayout inside the scrollview needs + the space that myTopButton takes up. 
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
   <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
     <ScrollView android:id="@+id/myscroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="65dip"
        android:paddingRight="2dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout style="@style/LinearLayoutInner"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout> 
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
            <Button android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:text="@string/search_viewdoses"/>
    </LinearLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
   <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-60dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/myText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@string/mytext"></TextView>
            <EditText android:id="@+id/myEdit" 
                android:layout_width="80dip"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/myText"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"></EditText>
            <Button android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:text="@string/mybuttontext"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

SCREEN NOW: [image]

SCREEN WANTED: [image]

Comment: You can set the `android:fillViewport` flag on the `ScrollView` in order to force it to not wrap the height on its content - give that a try.

Comment: I have already set android:fillViewport to true I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry, I completely overlooked that! I did notice that you're setting a bottom margin to the `ScrollView` (`android:layout_marginBottom="65dip"`) - isn't that simply causing the blue gap between the red and green layouts?

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the bottom margin from `topLayout` and add `android:layout_above="@+d/bottomLayout"` to it. You have to define the `bottomLayout` before `topLayout` in your xml though. I think you should also remove the top margin from your `bottomLayout`.

Same goes for the actual scrollView and the button.

Comment: Hmm, that made the scrollview + button take up the whole screen!?!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `android:layout_weight="1"` on the ScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

In the layout tag

```
   <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
```

just remove `android:layout_marginBottom="80dip"` and you should be ready to go. It's the one producing that ugly, unwanted space at the bottom of your top section.